# Splitting a string in Python to 3 segments appointed to 3 variables depending on item count

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension, python-2.x, try-except

I'm new to Python and struggling to solve the following issue the most Pythonic way.

I have a string (Example states given below) which needs to be split (`.split('/', 2)`) and appointed (up) to 3 variables (vars. a, b and c). The string is a URL which I need to split into 3 segments.

The string and its segments can be the following examples:

- 'seg_a/seb_b/the_rest' `-> a = seg_a, b = seg_b, c = the_rest`
- 'seg_a/the_rest' `-> a = seg_a, b = None, c = the_rest`
- 'seg_a' `-> a = seg_a, b = None, c = None`

**Note:** No obligation exists to have None value given if nothing else gets appointed. They simple **may** not exist (b in ex. 2, b and c in ex. 3).

If split results in 1 item, it's given to variable a.
If split results in 2 items, it's given to variable a and c
If split results in 3 items, then it's segments are given to variables a, b and c

I have found 2 methods achieving this, both seem not Pythonic, hence resulting in this question.

**Method A:**

```
Split.
Count.
Depending on count, appoint segments to variables with IF.. Elif.. Elif.. Else. statement
```

**Method B:**
Use list comprehension and nested Try-Except blocks. Ex:

```
try:
    a, b, c = [i for i in to_split.split("/", 2)]
except ValueError:
    try:
        a, c =  [i for i in to_split.split("/", 1)]
        b = None
    except ValueError:
        a = to_split
        b, c = None, None
```

**My question (short):**

- What is the correct, Pythonic way of splitting this string to its
  segments and appointing them to variables a, b and c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do:

```
l = to_split.split("/", 2)
a, b, c = l + [None] * (3 - len(l))
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, what is most Pythonic isn't what's most clever.  If something is simple, concise, and comprehensible at a glance, then use it and get on with your day.  If the rules you want to impose are

> If split results in 1 item, it's given to variable a.
>   If split results in 2 items, it's given to variables a and c.
>   If split results in 3 items, it's given to variables a, b and c.

Then just implement that, Method A-style.

```
p = to_split.split("/", 2)
if len(p) == 1:
    a, = p
elif len(p) == 2:
    a, c = p
elif len(p) == 3:
    a, b, c = p
else:
    raise ValueError("could not parse {}".format(to_split))
```

I can read this and know exactly what it's doing.  If there's a bug in there -- say I've swapped `b` and `c` when `len(p) == 2` -- it's easy to fix once I see the problem.

It does seem a little strange that you're willing to let variables be undefined -- you must branch later to avoid getting a `NameError`, and that could, and probably should, be avoided with some refactoring.  In my experience, something is probably a little off elsewhere.  Even without changing anything else, I'd include `a, b, c = [None]*3`, myself.

One rule which helps keep code maintainable is that we should try to minimize the distance between what we would tell someone an algorithm is supposed to do and how we told the computer what to do.  Here, since what you want to do is almost transcribable directly into Python, I'd just do that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
    a,b,c = (to_split("/",2) + [None]*3)[0:3]
```

However I agree with @DSM: the most pythonic way is not always the best approach to solve a problem. It could be ok at first, but a more verbose code works best in terms of readability.

That's one of the reasons I love Python: there are several ways to solve a problem, and it's up to the developer to choose the best according to his/her needs.